# Populating an array (defined in an object) with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, typeerror

I've ceated an object to fill into an array and define an array inside a different object:

```
    var ListEntry = function (name, code, order) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        this.order = order;
    }

    var myObject = Class.extend({
        list: new Array()
    })
```

Later this will be populated with data as such:

```
    var ListEntry = new ListEntry(cell[0], cell[1], cell[2]);
    this.list.push(ListEntry);
```

This throws a typeError: ListEntry is not a constructor, when trying to create the new object.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You should probably think about naming instances of `ListEntry` something other than `ListEntry`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var listEntry = new ListEntry(cell[0], cell[1], cell[2]);
this.list.push(listEntry);
```